Applying a transformation on an image based on a QR code
I would like to correct the perspective and scale of an image. The image contains a QR code (of known size EXPECTED_QR_SIZE), and I am using OpenCV functions to detect the QR code and apply perspective and scaling correction on the full image.
import cv2
import numpy as np

EXPECTED_QR_SIZE = 148

image = cv2.imread('page_1.jpg')

# Detect the QR code in the image
qrCodeDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
retval, decoded_info, points, straight_qrcode = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecodeMulti(image)
points = points.astype(int)
# Define the destination points for the perspective transformation
dest_pts = np.array([[0, 0], [EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1, 0], [EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1, EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1], [0, EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1]], dtype='float32')
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points.astype('float32'), dest_pts)
# Transformed the image and display it
transformed_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow('Image', transformed_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

When I run the code above, the QR code is corrected, but the entire image is offset (the QR code lies in the top corner).
##########################
##########################
EDIT 1
##########################
##########################
I have taken a new image:

the original image is : page_1_ori.
In this image the Code is located at (362,1322)

I have applied some transformations on the image that give : page_1


If I do use the following code (same code as above, adding dest_pts += [362, 1322]):
import cv2
import numpy as np

EXPECTED_QR_SIZE = 148

image = cv2.imread('page_1.jpg')

# Detect the QR code in the image
qrCodeDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
retval, decoded_info, points, straight_qrcode = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecodeMulti(image)
print('QR width, height:', points[0][1][0] - points[0][0][0], points[0][2][1] - points[0][1][1])
points = points.astype(int)
# Define the destination points for the perspective transformation
dest_pts = np.array([[0, 0], [EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1, 0], [EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1, EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1], [0, EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1]], dtype='float32')
dest_pts += [362, 1322]
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points.astype('float32'), dest_pts)
# Transformed the image and display it
transformed_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow('Image', transformed_image)
# save the image
cv2.imwrite('transformed_image.jpg', transformed_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

The QR code is at its original position but the correction is not so good.
##########################
##########################
EDIT 2
##########################
##########################
Removing points = points.astype(int) helps (obviously).

QR codes are not made for that. they are not Augmented Reality markers. you should use AR markers.

well yes, the transform positions the marker like that. if you want the output to be positioned differently, multiply a rotation and translation onto the homography. do you know where on the sheet the code is designed to be?

I understand QR code are not made for that but it seems to work nicely. Plus I can directly generate a QR code in LaTeX that can serve other purposes.

Yes I know the expected positon of the code.

if you know the expected position of the code, why won't you share it?

it is (362, 1321) for the top left corner

Then you should probably add dest_pts += [362, 1321] before the computation of your matrix. As is, you explicitely said that you wanted the top-left corner of your QR-code to be at (0,0), so there it is.

@chrslg no that's bad. have a translation matrix from the translation vector, then multiply it onto the homography. that's the right way. -- and that still doesn't include the marker's pose on the sheet, i.e. a matrix including its orientation. -- the example images do not show at all how the sheet is supposed to look. it's a page number, with some rotated stuff on it.

@ChristophRackwitz But isn't that exactly what cv2.getPerspectiveTransform will do? Provides the transformation matrix, including the translation parts, that matches? Or are you concerned by some condition number problem, or stability? I mean, on my computer it seems to do exactly what (I think, maybe also I misread the question) is expected: the same rotation as in OP's code, plus the needed translation so that qr-code ends with its corner at (362,1321)

sure you can do that, but I'd recommend introducing the translation right there, onto the homography matrix, instead of messing with the points. that's a lot more convenient. especially for adjustments that are not just a translation, but also involving a rotation, which it should in this instance. the goal isn't to put the code in the corner, but to put the entire sheet into view. that requires the code to be in some place, and orientation, that is not the corner.

Just have edited the post (Edit 1)

And have made 2 new EDIT

do not put answers into the question. take those out, and post answers instead. [answer]

##########################
##########################
EDIT 3
##########################
##########################
Here, I compare the 2 possibilities:

Add the translation directly to the homography matrix
OR translating destination points.

import cv2
import numpy as np

EXPECTED_QR_SIZE = 148

image = cv2.imread('page_1.jpg')

# Detect the QR code in the image
qrCodeDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
retval, decoded_info, points, straight_qrcode = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecodeMulti(image)
print('QR width, height:', points[0][1][0] - points[0][0][0], points[0][2][1] - points[0][1][1])
# Define the destination points for the perspective transformation
dest_pts = np.array([[0, 0], [EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1, 0], [EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1, EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1], [0, EXPECTED_QR_SIZE-1]], dtype='float32')
translation = np.array([362, 1322], dtype='float32')
# Compute the homography matrix
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points, dest_pts)
# Add the translation directly to the homography matrix
M[0, 2] += translation[0]  # Add translation on the x-axis
M[1, 2] += translation[1]  # Add translation on the y-axis
# Transformed the image and display it
transformed_image_1 = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
# save the image
cv2.imwrite('transformed_image_1.jpg', transformed_image_1)
# OR
dest_pts += translation
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points.astype('float32'), dest_pts)
# Transformed the image and display it
transformed_image_2 = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
cv2.imwrite('transformed_image_2.jpg', transformed_image_2)

transformed_image_1.jpg seems to give better results albeit the Code seems to be slightly distorted.

transformed_image_2.jpg is :

